# iphone - digital image processing

Tags: objective-c, iphone, image, image-manipulation

I want to build an app similar to Fat Booth, Aging Boot etc. I am totally noob to digital image processing. where should I start? Some hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Processing images on the iPhone with any kind of speed is going to require OpenGL ES. That would be the place to start. (If this is your first iOS project, though, I wouldn’t recommend starting off with GL.)

Apple has an image processing example available here: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html.

I imagine the apps you refer to use GL too. Fat Booth, for example, might texture a mesh with your photo, then distort the mesh to make the photo bulge out in the middle. It could also be done purely with fragment shaders.

Comment: Please answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33889683/how-to-implemet-digital-picture-frame-in-ios-app if you can..